# plotting histograms in pandas

Tags: pandas, plot, dataframe

I am looking to plot to sets of data each with 10 points in them in overlapping bins.

```
 values1 = [29, 31, 24, 30, 30, 14, 25, 35, 27, 31]
 values2 = [36, 29, 29, 29, 34, 33, 27, 34, 36, 39]
```

When I add them to a dataframe they come out as 2 columns.
i am looking to plot 2 rows each  with 10 overlapping columns.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(values1, values2)
```

and subsequently when I plot them using histograms they do not come out correctly

```
  df1.plot.hist(stacked = True)
  plt.show()
```

So my aim is to do a pairwise comparison between each of the numbers in the arrays. 29 - 36 , 31 - 29 , 24 - 29 etc.

I would like to plot them so that they overlap as this example
http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/_images/hist_new_stacked.png
however I have only to values instead of three as in example.

Comment: So are you asking for `df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'values1':values1, 'values2':values2}, orient='index')`?

Comment: Not quite, that produces 10 different colours and the same graph.I want 2 colours comparing each of the values plotted adjacently ?

Comment: It's really unclear what you want please edit your question with a graphical display of what you want

Answer (score 1):

You can pass them as values to a dict:

```
values1 = [29, 31, 24, 30, 30, 14, 25, 35, 27, 31]
values2 = [36, 29, 29, 29, 34, 33, 27, 34, 36, 39]
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'values1':values1, 'values2':values2})
df1.plot.hist(stacked = True)
```

[image]

What you did caused the ctor to interpret the passed values as a single column of data and then the index values:

```
pandas.DataFrame(data=None, index=None, columns=None, dtype=None, copy=False)
```

Compare the difference:

```
In [166]:
pd.DataFrame(values1, values2)

Out[166]:
     0
36  29
29  31
29  24
29  30
34  30
33  14
27  25
34  35
36  27
39  31

In [167]:
pd.DataFrame({'values1':values1, 'values2':values2})

Out[167]:
   values1  values2
0       29       36
1       31       29
2       24       29
3       30       29
4       30       34
5       14       33
6       25       27
7       35       34
8       27       36
9       31       39
```

Comment: yeah I was able to generate that graph, but  I was looking to plot the variables side by side, so that there are 10 bars adjacent to one another , showing the overlap  ?

Comment: You mean you want 2 rows instead of 10? Please edit your question with the desired output

Comment: Yeah your right , 2 rows and 10 columns. I will edit above.